# Can a rheostat (as an alternative to a relay) act as the correction unit in a thermostatically controlled electric heater?

Tags: control-system, electric-machine, heater, thermostat, rheostat

I was studying about the various elements present in a thermostatically controlled electric heater control system. While I agree that a relay can be used to correct the output temperature from a heating element based on the inputs to the system, I was wondering if a rheostat connected in series to the resister acting as the heating element could substitute for the relay? This setup would work on the principle that a variance in the rheostat's resistance would cause a change in the current flowing through the whole circuit thus varying the heat output from the heating element.

Comment: And then your rheostat will turn into a heating element by itself.... Also, who will actuate the rheostat? You will need to add some kind of motor or other actuator, controlled by the temperature.

Comment: firstly, thank you for commenting. secondly, let's say if we add an actuator to control the rheostat's resistance, would the setup work. Also, this setup wouldn't be very viable because If both rheostat and the heating element dissipate a significant amount of heat, the heater will get hot very easily raising safety concerns, correct?

Comment: P.s I am a complete beginner.

Comment: There are other methods of regulating voltage/current on the load, not involving "wasting" the "excess". Can be PWM in case of DC, or "chopping" the AC using triac as dimmers do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this. For example, you could have a motor-driven rheostat with the rheostat position determined by a controller.

You could also use an active device such as a transistor in place of the rheostat. An example where you'd find this in real life would be some kind of ovenized component such as a [precision voltage reference](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTZ1000.pdf) or a crystal oscillator. In such cases the efficiency is not too important because the power consumption of the 'oven' is rather low (hundreds of mW steady-state in the case of the linked LTZ1000), and it's also desirable to avoid electrical noise that would be caused by switching.

For higher powers, we'd want to avoid using a linear component to control the current though, because of the losses. For a constant-resistance element, worst case is 50% efficiency (when the external resistance equals the heater resistance). At 100% on there are no external losses and at 0% on there is no heating in either the heater or the external (infinite) resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work - however:

- The rheostat would dissipate significant heat itself. You'd want to couple it to the thing you're trying to heat, so the heat isn't wasted, and then, you might as well use the rheostat **as** the heater (no need for a separate heater!)
- How will you adjust the rheostat?

Answer (score 0):

An energy regulator (also known as a 'Simmerstat') may be used to obtain the desired temperature.

[image]

It provides 'on / off' control using a heating coil to heat the bi-metallic strip that carries the moving contact. Thermal deformation of the strip opens the contact.

The duty cycle is adjusted by varying the spring pressure on the strip.